# Categorical data in R with h2o

Tags: r, logistic-regression, h2o, categorical-data

I have run a logistical regression model with both categorical and numerical variables. The model was trying to predict the number of website visits in a month based off the first week. Obviously the number of website visits in the first week was the strongest indicator. However when i ran h2o deep learning with various models and activation functions the model performs very poorly. Based off the var_imp function it gives importance to very non important variables(based off my logistical regression model, which is quite good, this is wrong), and only seems to have categorical subsets ranked with high importance. and the model does not perform well even on the training data, a real warning sign! So i just wanted to upload my code to check i am not doing anything to harm the model. It seems strange for logistical regression to get it quiteright but deep learning to get it so wrong, so i imagine its something i've done!

```
summary(data)
 $ VAR1: Factor w/ 8 levels ,..: 1 5 2 1 7 2 5 1 5 1 ...
  $ VAR2: Factor w/ 5 levels ,..: 1 4 1 1 4 4 4 1 1 4 ...
  $ VAR3: Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  $ VAR4: Factor w/ 2 levels : 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
  $ VAR5         : num  1000 20 30 20 30 30 30 50 30 400 ...
  $ VAR6: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
  $ VAR7: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
  $ VAR8: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  $ VAR9: num  56 52 49 29 28 38 34 79 53 36 ...
  $ VAR10: num  3 2 1 3 2 2 3 4 2 2 ...
  $ VAR11: num  1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  $ VAR12: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ VAR13: num  1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  $ VAR14: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ VAR15: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ VAR16: num  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
  $ VAR17: num  19 7 1 4 10 2 4 4 7 12 ...
  $ VAR18: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
  $ VAR19: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","Y": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ VAR20: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ VAR21: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ VAR22:    : num  0.579 0 0 0 0.4 ...
  $ VAR23: num  1.89 1 1 1 2.9 ...
  $ VAR24: num  0.02962 0.00691 0.05327 0.02727 0.01043 ...
  $ VAR25: Factor w/ 3 levels ..: 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 1 3 ...
  $ VAR26: num  3 2 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 4 ...
  $ VAR27: num  3 2 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  $ VAR_RESPONSE: num  7 24 4 3 8 12 5 48 2 7 ...

sapply(data,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

colSums(is.na(data))
data[is.na(data)] = 0



 d.hex = as.h2o(data, destination_frame= "d.hex")

 Data_g.split = h2o.splitFrame(data = d.hex,ratios = 0.75)
 Data_train = Data_g.split[[1]]#75% training data
 Data_test = Data_g.split[[2]]

 activation_opt <- 
c("Rectifier","RectifierWithDropout","Maxout","MaxoutWithDropout", 
"Tanh","TanhWithDropout")
 hidden_opt <- list(c(10,10),c(20,15),c(50,50,50),c(5,3,2),c(100,100),c(5),c(30,30,30),c(50,50,50,50),c(5,4,3,2))
 l1_opt <- c(0,1e-3,1e-5,1e-7,1e-9)
 l2_opt <- c(0,1e-3,1e-5,1e-7,1e-9)

 hyper_params <- list( activation=activation_opt,
                  hidden=hidden_opt,
                  l1=l1_opt,
                  l2=l2_opt )

 search_criteria <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", max_models=30)

 dl_grid10 <- h2o.grid("deeplearning"
                ,grid_id = "deep_learn10"
                ,hyper_params = hyper_params
                ,search_criteria = search_criteria
                ,x = 1:27
                ,y = "VAR_RESPONSE"
                ,training_frame = Data_train)
d_grid10 <- h2o.getGrid("deep_learn10",sort_by = "mse")

mn = h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:27,
                 y = "VAR_RESPONSE",
                 training_frame = Data_train,
                 model_id = "mn",
                 activation = "Maxout",
                 l1 = 0,
                 l2 = 1e-9,
                 hidden = c(100,100),)
```

Comment: in the future you can always edit a post, you don't need to delete it and then repost. Please also note that it's good to provide a fully reproducible code snippet.

Comment: Hi Lauren, yes sorry when i tried to edit the post it said i had code that wasn't formatted, when in actual fact it was just text so i had to delete and reload.

Comment: no worries! thanks for letting me know.